# How to renable document.write after jQuery ajax has completed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to grab a snippet of JS that has document.write in it - this causes the page to go blank once the document.write renders. I was able to work around this by redefining document.write and pass the response of the script to a function that I use to output the response from the getScript() jQuery function. I am having an issue however with other elements and scripts that load later in the page that my redefining is preventing to output on the page. How can I set document.write back to the default functionality after the jQuery getScript() has completed?

```
$.getScript('somescript.com/script/', function(){
  //Prevent document.write normal behavior
  document.write = function(markup) {
  fullMarkup += markup;
  appendResponse(markup);
  }
 }  
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just save the original refernce to  `document.write` in some variable and restore it, after you used the replacement.

```
window.backupWrite = document.write;
```

and after succesfull loading (and execution) of your script

```
document.write = window.backupWrite;
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you execute `document.write` after everything has loaded, it will blank the page.

If your aim was just to retrieve and execute the script, `$.getScript()` already does that for you.

```
$.getScript('somescript.com/script/');
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.write` completely clears the DOM if it is run after the document has rendered in some big browsers.  That is to say, don't use it.  If you don't have a choice with your external script, that's too bad.  You can add the contents in string form using the various jQuery `.append` methods.